# solve $(3xy-2ay^2)dx+(x^2-2axy)dy=0$ using exact DE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$(3xy-2ay^2)dx+(x^2-2axy)dy=0$$ (a is a given constant ) .can be easily solved using homogenous DE method .But can this DE be solved using exact DE method ?I tried it using exact DE method but failed .

Comment: Grouping like terms together you can get $\frac1x\,d(x^3y)-2ay\,d(xy)=0$, which can easily be completed to an integrable form.

Comment: @LutzLehmann yeah but 1/x  and y cause the problem

Comment: @LutzLehmann i reduced till this form but failed to bring it into integrable form

Comment: The terms separate from each other might appear problematic, but combine them together to get a perfectly solvable equation.

Comment: @LutzLehmann how to plan to further combine these ?

Comment: Just multiply with $x$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann yeah , i missed observing it .It was a stupid q